# tcsh scripting, problems with find and special characters in file names or directory names

Tags: tcsh

Im a beginner scripter, writing scripts in tcsh and csh(these are teached in my course)

Im writing a script which uses find for putting path of directories 
this is the part of the script:

```
set list = (`find $PATH -type d`)
```

it works fine until the file or directory names arent named such as:
@fi@@lename&& or −filename or :−,?!drectoryanem!-``

These special characters i couldnt handle i changed the find script to:

```
set list = ("`find $PATH -type d`")
```

bit none of these works, when i want to use the path from the list in this next script:

```
foreach i ($list:q)
   foreach file (`find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f`)
   ....
   end
end
```

it couldnt handle these special file names, so i get many errors like find: −."!filename:  no such filename or directory

Comment: Could you tell us the name of the school where `csh` is still teached? Just so that other can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out

It had to be this way:

```
set subor = ("`find "'"$i"'" -type f -maxdepth 1`")
```

now it ignores everything in the filenames

and in:

```
foreach j ($subor:q)
```

i quoted it this way it ignores the white characters in file names